# Find the equation of the secant line through the points where x has the given values

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(x)=x^2+3x; x=3, x=4$

$A. y=10x-12$

$B. y=10x+12$

$C. y=12x-10$

$D. y=10x$

I can't find this anywhere in my notes so I am not sure where to start this one. Would I try to find the derivative of the original equation or maybe utilize the rate of change formula?

Update: After applying the rate of change formula I have concluded that$ y=10x-12.$ I was wondering if anyone could tell me if this is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need calculus for this. Notice how the question is asking for the equation of the **secant** line through two points, not the tangent line at a point.

We begin by finding the slope of the secant line. Using the function definition, we determine that $(3, 18)$ and $(4, 28)$ are two points that define the secant. The slope is simply $m = \frac{28 - 18}{4 - 3} = 10.$

Now we use one of our points (I'll use $(3, 18)$ here) to see that the y-intercept of the line is $(0, -12).$ So the answer is $\text{(A)} y = 10x - 12.$

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me!